# Repeated Eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, dynamical-systems

Two problems from *Differential Equations; Dynamical Systems,  and an Introduction to Chaos* (Morris W. Hirsch,Stephen Smale.Robert L. Devaney), examples page 112,113:

If $$A= \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 0 & -1 \\
        0 & 2 &  1 \\
        -1 & -1 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$
… $\lambda =2 , m_{\lambda}=3$ $rank(A-2I)=2 , n_{\lambda}=1 ,k= m_{\lambda}- n_{\lambda}+1=3$ so
 $$p= \begin{pmatrix}
        1& 0 & 1 \\
        -1 & 0 &  0 \\
        0 & -1 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$ by $v_2=(A-2I)v_3, v_1=(A-2I)v_2, v_3 : \begin{cases}
(A-2I)^3v_3= 0\\
(A-2I)^2v_3 \not = 0\\
\end{cases}
$But $p^{-1}Ap \not =J$  $$p= \begin{pmatrix}
        0& 0 & 0 \\
        0& 1 &  0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} \not = \begin{pmatrix}
        2& 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 &  1 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$  what’s wrong?!

Comment: I don't see a [jordan algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_algebra) anywhere. Are the tags correct?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen matrix $J$ is jordan form of $A$

Comment: Jordan algebra means something else. See the link. For questions about Jordan forms the recommended tag is *matrices*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume you understand how they derived $P$. (If not, please respond).

We have:

$$P= \begin{pmatrix}1& 0 & 1 \\-1 & 0 &  0 \\0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

This give us:

$$P^{-1}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & -1 \\1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

From this we get:

$$P^{-1}AP = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & -1 \\1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 & -1 \\0 & 2 &  1 \\-1 & -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1& 0 & 1 \\-1 & 0 &  0 \\0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 &  1 \\0 & 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$

This validates the authors' solution.

Did you calculate $P^{-1}$ or the product $P^{-1}AP$ incorrectly?

Comment: ok that's right. $p^{-1}$ is wrong by me.

Comment: Day was slowish...but okay. At least we can say TGIF!!

Comment: Yes...dead-pan slow (and likely slow weekend ahead of us!)